# Alpine Linuxのashでgit-promptのようなのを出す設定方法

Tags: git, shell

件名のとおりです。
Alpine Linuxのashでgit-promptのようなのを出す設定方法を知りたいです。

### 現状

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v ${my_git_project_dir}:/app -w /app alpine    
/app #
```

### 期待する動作

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v ${my_git_project_dir}:/app -w /app alpine

# $ なにか設定をする

[ブランチ名やchange_status] /app #
```

Answer (score 0):

以下に書こうとしている内容を知ってる上でashで出来ないかを質問しているのであればすみません。
Alpine Linuxにパッケージでbashを入れた上でbashをシェルとして使う前提で設定するのが良いのではないでしょうか?

bashやzshだと、git-prompt.shで定義されている__git_ps1関数を使用する方法がネット検索が色々出てくると思います。ashではおそらくそのまま動かないと思います。
git-prompt.shをashでも動くようにすれば良いのでしょうけどざっとネット検索してみてもそのような作業をしているひとは見かけませんでした。(探し方が悪かっただけかもしれません。)

昨今のgitを含む様々なツールを使った開発環境のエコシステムにのっかるためには、どうしてもbashまたはzshにせざるを得ない部分が多いという気がします。
逆に言うとbashやzshにすれば、他のひとの作った便利なエコシステムの恩恵を簡単に受けることが出来るということです。

Comment: すみません。こっちの意味です。  >「以下に書こうとしている内容を知ってる上でashで出来ないかを質問している」